# How to copy a small part of an array from global memory into the local memory of a thread

Tags: cuda

I have an nxn matrix A (which is stored row by row in an array) with floats. n is divisible by 4. I now want to output a matrix B which is (n/4)x(n/4). In B i want to store the arithmetic middle of all the values of a 4 by 4 sub matrix in A. The submatrixes do not overlap. E.g. If A were 16x16, B would be 4x4, since A has 4 submatrixes.

The thing is, that i want to you use 1 thread per submatrix and i want to have the memory access as coalescent as possible. My idea was to create a kernel and in thread 0 read the values A[0],A[1],A[2],A[3] and in thread 2 A[4],A[5],A[6],A[7]. The thing is, that if i execute these reads after one another (this code only works for the first row of the matrix) e.g.:

```
float * firstRow[4];
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++):
    firstRow[i] = A[threadIdx.x * 4 + i];
```

the reads would not be coalescent. i would need something like cudaMemcpy but from global memory to a threads memory.

I am not sure if i could copy the whole array into shared memory since it is 4 times bigger than the number of threads. Nevertheless, i want to know the answer to my original question.

Comment: Cooperatively loading into shared memory sounds like the right idea. In this case the big size of the submatrix is not necessarily problematic, as you do not need the full submatrix in memory for your operation. Just stream the data through shared memory in chunks that fit into it. Depending on the size of the submatrices you might even want to use more than one thread per reduction. E.g. use warp intrinsics to get a whole warp to compute it.

Comment: CUB has functionality for cooperatively loading data through shared memory. See [`cub::BlockLoad`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_load.html), especially using the `ALGORITHM`s with `TRANSPOSE`.

Comment: If you use Ampere or newer architectures, you can also try to use the asynchronous `memcpy_async` to load data into shared memory, as shown in [Controlling Data Movement to Boost Performance on the NVIDIA Ampere Architecture](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/controlling-data-movement-to-boost-performance-on-ampere-architecture/). On older architectures you get a very slow fallback though in my experience.

Comment: Shared memory or registers themselves are preferable to local memory.

Comment: You can read `float4` in a coalesced way, 4*4*32=512 Bytes per warp instruction. So you get 4 columns for each thread, repeat 4 instructions for the 4 rows. It is in this case probably still fully coalesced, when groups of 8 threads have data beside each other, test with your GPU and Compute Nsight. Be careful for correct alignment for coalesced access.

Comment: To further increase speed, fuse your kernel with operations before or after. As the global memory speed will be the limit.